# How to create SSO from domain java web client to non domain web server using LDAP authentication

Tags: windows, jsp, tomcat, servlets, single-sign-on

I want to create a SSO using windows domain from java web application to web server in non domain. I have created the same with web server and web client both in domains. But i want to achieve the same with client in domain and server in non domain zone . I want to pass ldap credentials in my web server. This has to be a complete windows domain SSO.

Answer (score 0):

Complete SSO in Java for Web means [SPNEGO with Kerberos](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/). Nothing else. No Basic, no LDAP or whatsoever.